# Простейший сервлет.Ошибка HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat, http-status-code-404, error404

Возникает ошибка 404. Раньше все работало корректно.
Перепробовал различные возможные вариации, использовал разный tomcat, пробовал аннотации и т.д.
Делал новый проект строго по рабочей инструкции, тщетно.
Складывается ощущении, ошибка в чем то другом.
Подскажите, как исправить данную проблему?

Код элементарный, стандратный

сервет:

```
import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.print("Hello");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

лог

```
"E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2020-02-26 02:33:03,509] Artifact TestServlet:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "E:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestServlet"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "E:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2"
Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.691 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 5 2020 22:26:25 UTC
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.51.0
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             E:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.694 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           13.0.2+8
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.694 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.694 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         E:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestServlet
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.694 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.696 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=E:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestServlet\conf\logging.properties
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.699 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.700 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=E:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestServlet\jmxremote.password
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=E:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestServlet\jmxremote.access
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.702 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.702 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_TestServlet
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.702 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.702 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.51\temp
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [E:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;E:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;E:\Windows\system32;E:\Windows;E:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Windows\system32;E:\Windows;E:\Windows\System32\Wbem;E:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;E:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3\bin;;.]
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.759 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.895 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Feb-2020 14:33:04.938 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 787 ms
26-Feb-2020 14:33:05.012 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
26-Feb-2020 14:33:05.013 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
26-Feb-2020 14:33:05.042 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
26-Feb-2020 14:33:05.089 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 149 ms
Connected to server
[2020-02-26 02:33:05,180] Artifact TestServlet:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
26-Feb-2020 14:33:05.725 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [115] milliseconds.
[2020-02-26 02:33:05,757] Artifact TestServlet:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2020-02-26 02:33:05,758] Artifact TestServlet:war exploded: Deploy took 578 milliseconds
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А по какому урлу 404 получаете?

Comment: Урл указываю верный

Comment: Добавьте скрины настройки Tomcat.

Comment: Добавил скрин, вроде все верно.

Comment: И вкладку deployment тоже или что написано в application context

Answer (score 1):

Так у Вас томкат на 8888 порту поднимается. Пробуйте

```
 localhost:8888/test
```

Comment: Да, это не ошибка, проверял, менял порт. Проблема осталась и при 8888, поменял обратно на 8080.